# Run external program in Beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref, external

I have Xubuntu 18.04 and TeXstudio 2.12.6. I want --- if possible --- run an external program in Beamer.

I searched the net for a solution where  I found a lot of stuff some links claiming that this is the solution, but nothing that worked for me.

Here is the code I tried with several pdfviewers:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\href{run:/usr/bin/octave}{\beamergotobutton{Link}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And it did not work.

Question:

If it is possible at all to run an external program in Beamer,
what do I have to do for this?

Thanks
Karl

Comment: It might be a problem with your viewers. Some viewers disallow running external programs for security reasons. Did you check that your viewers allow it?

Comment: Ok, for which viewer does it work? I have a number of them.

Comment: `octave` must be run in a terminal.  Try something like `xterm -e /usr/bin/octave`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: you don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}`, beamer already loads the package

Comment: @Karl Does the comment by AlexG solve your problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: @samcarter, yes it works with the xpdf viewer. Sorry for the late answer, I didn't have time earlier.